# Delphi extracting multiple extras data from intent crashes the app with segfault 11

Tags: delphi, android-intent

To handle intents I'm using this component:

https://github.com/barisatalay/delphi-android-broadcast-receiver-component.

My app has 2 different intent receivers. The first intent outputs just 1 tag (DATA) as an array of float, the second intent has 3 tags (SUM_DATA, MIN_DATA and MAX_DATA) that are each an array of float.

Here is how I register them:

```
procedure TMainScreen.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HRBroadcastReceiver.RegisterReceive;
  AccelBroadcastReceiver.RegisterReceive;
end;

procedure TMainScreen.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);     //start button
begin
  HRDataStr := StringToJString('DATA');
  SUMDataStr := StringToJString('SUM_DATA');
  MINDataStr := StringToJString('MIN_DATA');
  MAXDataStr := StringToJString('MAX_DATA');
  HRBroadcastReceiver.Add(HR_DATA);
  AccelBroadcastReceiver.Add(ACCEL_DATA);
end;
```

Here is my parsing code:

```
procedure TMainScreen.AccelBroadcastReceiverReceive(Context: JContext;
  Intent: JIntent);
var
  MINArr, MAXArr, SUMArr: TJavaArray<Single>;
  csv_buffer: string;
begin
  {$I-}
  try
    if Intent.hasExtra(SUMDataStr) = true then
    begin
      SUMArr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(SUMDataStr);
      if (SUMArr <> nil) and (SUMArr.Length > 0) then
      begin
        ACCEL_SUM := SUMArr[0];
        if (ACCEL_SUM <= no_data) then ACCEL_SUM := -1;
      end else
        ACCEL_SUM := -1;
    end;

    if Intent.hasExtra(SUMDataStr) = true then
    begin
      MINArr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(MINDataStr);
      if (MINArr <> nil) and (MINArr.Length > 0) then
      begin
        ACCEL_MIN := MINArr[0];
        if (ACCEL_MIN <= no_data) then ACCEL_MIN := -1;
      end else
        ACCEL_MIN := -1;
    end;

    if Intent.hasExtra(SUMDataStr) = true then
    begin
      MAXArr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(MAXDataStr);
      if (MAXArr <> nil) and (MAXArr.Length > 0) then
      begin
        ACCEL_MAX := MAXArr[0];
        if (ACCEL_MAX <= no_data) then ACCEL_MAX := -1;
      end else
        ACCEL_SUM := -1;

      if ( (ACCEL_SUM = -1) and (ACCEL_MAX = -1) and (ACCEL_MIN = -1) ) then
      begin
        HR := -1;
        Label2.Text := FloatToStr(HR);
      end;

      csv_buffer := FloatToStr(HR) + ',' + FloatToStr(ACCEL_SUM) + ',' + FloatToStr(ACCEL_MAX) + ',' + FloatToStr(ACCEL_MIN);
      if (Remcue.IsChecked = true) then csv_buffer := csv_buffer + ',' + FloatToStr(HRV) + ',' + IntToStr(STAGE);
      Remcue.Text := 'REM Alarm (beta)   REM detected:' + IntToStr(remcue.Tag);
      Label1.Text := FloatToStr(ACCEL_SUM);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(csv_buffer);
      AccelTimer.Tag := 0;
    end;
  {$I+}
  except
    on E : Exception do
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Accel Exception = ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Sometimes it is not working as it should. It does crash the app sometimes with segfault 11 right after clicking the start button (Button3 in my case, see the code above). Sometimes I get exception:
Access violation at address C84E2FC6, accessing address 00000018 and the app continues to run normally. Or it could just run normally.

I'm sure I'm missing something - I'm new to delphi on android coding. Thanks!

UPD1: Thanks to Remy Lebeau I've fixed some copy/pasting errors.

Comment: Those copy/paste errors were a key culprit of your problem. Rather than edit your question to fix them (thus invalidating the whole question), you should post the fixed code as an answer instead. I have reverted your edit.  However, if you fix the mistakes and are still having problems, then yes, do update the question with your latest code.  And BTW, please debug your code.  You should be able to report the exact line of code that is crashing.

Comment: It's not possible to make a copy paste error. The error is not copy pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segfault 11 is Android's<sup>1</sup> equivalent of an Access Violation in Windows.

<sup>1</sup>: well, Linux's equivalent, but Android is built on top of Linux.

An Access Violation near address 0 usually means a `nil` pointer is being accessed. I see several typos in your code that could be causing that.

For example:

```
if Intent.hasExtra(SUMDataStr) = true then // <-- should be MINDataStr instead!
begin
  MINArr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(MINDataStr);
```

You are querying for the existence of the `SUMDataStr` field, but then you are retrieving the array for the `MINDataStr` field instead.  If the requested field does not exist, `getFloatArrayExtra()` will return `nil`.

Same with the `MAXDataStr` array field:

```
if Intent.hasExtra(SUMDataStr) = true then // <-- should be MAXDataStr instead!
begin
   MAXArr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(MAXDataStr);
```

Also, if `MAXArr` is nil or empty, you are assigning your `-1` value to your `ACCEL_SUM` variable instead of your `ACCEL_MAX` variable:

```
if Intent.hasExtra(SUMDataStr) = true then
begin
  MAXArr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(MAXDataStr);
  if (MAXArr <> nil) and (MAXArr.Length > 0) then
  begin
    ACCEL_MAX := MAXArr[0];
    if (ACCEL_MAX <= no_data) then ACCEL_MAX := -1;
  end else
    ACCEL_SUM := -1; // <-- should be ACCEL_MAX instead!
```

---

On a side note, your UI handling is inside the `if` block for the `MAXDataStr` array retrieval. Is that where you really want it? If so, the UI will only be updated if that specific field is present (making your other variables useless).

Or, do you want the UI updated whenever the `Intent` is received, regardless of the fields it provides? If so (and I suspect this is what you really want), you need to move the UI code outside of that `if` block:

```
procedure TMainScreen.AccelBroadcastReceiverReceive(Context: JContext;
  Intent: JIntent);
var
  MINArr, MAXArr, SUMArr: TJavaArray<Single>;
  csv_buffer: string;
begin
  {$I-}
  try
    if Intent.hasExtra(SUMDataStr) = true then
    begin
      SUMArr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(SUMDataStr);
      if (SUMArr <> nil) and (SUMArr.Length > 0) then
      begin
        ACCEL_SUM := SUMArr[0];
        if (ACCEL_SUM <= no_data) then ACCEL_SUM := -1;
      end else
        ACCEL_SUM := -1;
    end;

    if Intent.hasExtra(MINDataStr) = true then
    begin
      MINArr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(MINDataStr);
      if (MINArr <> nil) and (MINArr.Length > 0) then
      begin
        ACCEL_MIN := MINArr[0];
        if (ACCEL_MIN <= no_data) then ACCEL_MIN := -1;
      end else
        ACCEL_MIN := -1;
    end;

    if Intent.hasExtra(MAXDataStr) = true then
    begin
      MAXArr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(MAXDataStr);
      if (MAXArr <> nil) and (MAXArr.Length > 0) then
      begin
        ACCEL_MAX := MAXArr[0];
        if (ACCEL_MAX <= no_data) then ACCEL_MAX := -1;
      end else
        ACCEL_MAX := -1;
    end; // <-- 'end' moved here!

    if ( (ACCEL_SUM = -1) and (ACCEL_MAX = -1) and (ACCEL_MIN = -1) ) then
    begin
      HR := -1;
      Label2.Text := FloatToStr(HR);
    end;

    csv_buffer := FloatToStr(HR) + ',' + FloatToStr(ACCEL_SUM) + ',' + FloatToStr(ACCEL_MAX) + ',' + FloatToStr(ACCEL_MIN);
    if (Remcue.IsChecked = true) then csv_buffer := csv_buffer + ',' + FloatToStr(HRV) + ',' + IntToStr(STAGE);
    Remcue.Text := 'REM Alarm (beta)   REM detected:' + IntToStr(remcue.Tag);
    Label1.Text := FloatToStr(ACCEL_SUM);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(csv_buffer);
    AccelTimer.Tag := 0;

    // <-- 'end' removed from here!
  {$I+}
  except
    on E : Exception do
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Accel Exception = ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

That being said, I would suggest simplifying your procedure to avoid duplicate code, and fix the mistakes mentioned above.  Try something more like this:

```
procedure TMainScreen.AccelBroadcastReceiverReceive(Context: JContext; Intent: JIntent);
var
  csv_buffer: string;

  function GetIntentFloatValue(Key: JString): Single;
  var
    Arr: TJavaArray<Single>;
  begin
    Arr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(Key);
    if (Arr <> nil) and (Arr.Length > 0) then
    begin
      Result := Arr[0];
      if (Result <= no_data) then Result := -1;
    end else
      Result := -1;
  end;

begin
  try
    ACCEL_SUM := GetIntentFloatValue(SUMDataStr);
    ACCEL_MIN := GetIntentFloatValue(MINDataStr);
    ACCEL_MAX := GetIntentFloatValue(MAXDataStr);

    if (ACCEL_SUM = -1) and (ACCEL_MAX = -1) and (ACCEL_MIN = -1) then
    begin
      HR := -1;
      Label2.Text := FloatToStr(HR);
    end;

    csv_buffer := Format('%f,%f,%f,%f', [HR, ACCEL_SUM, ACCEL_MAX, ACCEL_MIN]);
    if Remcue.IsChecked then csv_buffer := csv_buffer + Format(',%f,%d', [HRV, STAGE]);
    Remcue.Text := 'REM Alarm (beta)   REM detected:' + IntToStr(Remcue.Tag);
    Label1.Text := FloatToStr(ACCEL_SUM);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(csv_buffer);
    AccelTimer.Tag := 0;
  except
    on E : Exception do
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Accel Exception = ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Oh, my bad. Just right before copying the code here I've used one DataStr and one Arr, as in your other answer, but later decided to convert it - that's why so many copy/pasting errors. Fixed now, but still crashing. I'll update the code in a second.

Comment: Thanks! This is much better compared to my implementation of this) Still crashing though. I'll try to debug, but somehow in new Delphi even breakpoints are not working, I'll have to investigate more.

Comment: The crash was caused my TMemo. Right now I'm using TStringList to store the data and everything is fine. Thanks for your help! Your code is great!